# noexcept, inheriting constructors and the invalid use of an incomplete type that is actually complete

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, noexcept, inheriting-constructors

I'm not sure if it's a bug of the *GCC* compiler or the intended behavior of `noexcept`.
Consider the following example:

```
struct B {
    B(int) noexcept { }
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct D: public B {
    using B::B;
    D() noexcept(noexcept(D{42})): B{42} { }
    void f() override { }
};

int main() {
    B *b = new D{};
}
```

If the `noexcept` is removed, it compiles.
Anyway, as it is in the example, I got this error from GCC v5.3.1:

```
test.cpp:8:31: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct D’
     D() noexcept(noexcept(D{42})): B{42} { }
                               ^
```

As far as I know, `struct D` is not an incomplete type, but inheriting constructors are involved in the statement and it looks like the compiler is actually considering the completeness of the base struct `B` more than of `D`.

Is that the intended behavior or is it legal code?

For the sake of clarity:

- [here](http://goo.gl/LzWlya) the compilation succeeds using *clang 3.7.1*
- [here](http://goo.gl/OxkUvU) the compilation fails using *GCC 5.3.0*

See [this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70077) to the *bugzilla* for the GCC compiler for further details.
Currently, the bug is still unconfirmed. I'll update the question as soon as possible.

Comment: Hmm, Clang 3.7.1 accepts this code.  I bet this is a GCC bug.

Comment: Yeah, to me it sounds much more as a bug in the GCC compiler, but it could also be a bug in clang!! I'm not sure it's valid code, even though it looks ok to me. A language lawyer would help here. :-)

Comment: I've added the location that the compiler is complaining about, along with a definitive version for future Googlers (the latest stable GCC as of this writing).

Comment: @thirtythreeeforty Thank you, much appreciated. It's a sign (at least to me) that you find the question interesting. Nice.

Comment: Yeah definitely.  This actually gets pretty far into the language-lawyer definitions of C++ grammar.  Hope my answer is rigorous enough for you :P

Comment: @dyp Other versions of GCC works fine indeed. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fdbd0c1c70e74f64) as an example, this is the code used for [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777287/determine-whether-a-constructor-of-an-abstract-base-class-is-noexcept/35791076#35791076) and it is based on the same idea.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty No, wait, actually [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81552252ead0d349) code does not compile even on the web, but the error is more meaningful. It says also `main.cpp:6:8: note: definition of 'struct D' is not complete until the closing brace`. Still I think it's an error of the GCC compiler.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code is legal, even though GCC claims otherwise.  It takes offense at this funny-looking declaration:

```
D() noexcept(noexcept(D{42}));
```

The outermost `noexcept` is a [noexcept specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec), stating that `D::D()` is noexcept if and only if its constant-expression argument evaluates to true.  The inner `noexcept` is a [noexcept operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) that checks at compile time whether its argument expression, which is not actually evaluated, throws no exceptions.  Because `D::D(int)` is noexcept (inherited from B), this should be true.

cppreference.com explicitly notes that using the operator inside the specifier is allowed (emphasis added):

> The noexcept operator performs a compile-time check that returns true if an expression is declared to not throw any exceptions.
>
> **It can be used within a function template's noexcept specifier to declare that the function will throw exceptions for some types but not others.**

Now, the class should be considered *complete* within the noexcept specifier due to §9.2.2 of the Standard (bold emphasis added):

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (3.9) (or complete type) at the closing `}` of the *class-specifier*. **Within the class *member-specification*, the class is regarded as complete within** function bodies, default arguments, *using-declaration*s introducing inheriting constructors (12.9), ***exception-specification*s**, and *brace-or-equal-initializer*s for non-static data members (including such things in nested classes). Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete within its own class *member-specification*.

§15.4.1 defines an *exception-specification* as the following grammar:

> *exception-specification*:
>
> - *dynamic-exception-specification*
> - *noexcept-specification*

So GCC should not reject your code.

Comment: As of this writing, I don't see a GCC ticket for this particular issue.  Maybe you could file one?

Comment: I think so, yes!  You might link back to this answer, or copy relevant bits (mostly the second half).

Comment: Updated question. Good hint. Thank you.

Comment: I'm to accept your answer, but I'd like to know if it's actually a bug or not before to flag it (know it from the ticket for the GCC compiler). If it is not, you still deserve an upvote, but for the sake of clarity there will be the need for a new answer that says that it is not a bug. Right?

Comment: If it isn't a GCC bug, I deserve a downvote ;).  That sounds fine.

Comment: Absolutely - if it isn't a bug, you still deserve an upvote, because I completely agree on your interpretation of the standard!! The fact that the GCC maintainers can reject the ticket saying that it is not a bug won't convince me that it is not a bug!! :-D

Comment: Still unconfirmed. Does it take so long usually for a bug of GCC to be confirmed?

Comment: No idea. I've never filed one, although I have recommended that several be filed based on SO posts.