# Why does making a virtual function pure (= 0) suppress std::is_nothrow_move_constructible?

Tags: c++

Why does this *code* only compile if I remove the `= 0`?

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo
{
    virtual ~Foo() noexcept = default;
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(Foo &&) noexcept = default;
    Foo(Foo const &) = default;
    Foo &operator =(Foo &&) noexcept = default;
    Foo &operator =(Foo const &) = default;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<Foo>::value);
```

Comment: Seems my question was a partial duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/35777287/541686

Answer (score 2):

**Short version:**
A variable of abstract type cannot be constructed. Removing the `= 0` makes the class no longer abstract.

**Long version:**
First, I would like to simplify the question since the "nothrow" part is a (potentially confusing) red herring. The`static_assert` still fails if "nothrow" is removed, as in

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_move_constructible<Foo>::value);
```

The definition of [`std::is_move_constructible<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_move_constructible) leads to the definition of [`std::is_constructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible). These combine to say that `std::is_move_constructible<Foo>::value` is true only when a variable of type `Foo` can be constructed from a value of type `Foo&&`. Since `Foo` is an abstract type (with the `= 0` in its definition), this construction – in fact, construction from any collection of parameter types – is not allowed. Hence the `value` is false and the `static_assert` fails.

Comment: +1, and to clarify: this implies it's impossible to tell if an abstract class has any particular kind of constructor—correct? (In my case I was trying to detect nothrow-ness, but then ran into this.) I guess it's one difference between the old `has_XYZ_constructor` proposal and the `is_XYZ_constructible` that we actually got - just because a constructor exists that doesn't mean anyone can call it!

Comment: @user541686 Can't you inherit from this class and test by calling that constructor from the derived class?

Comment: @Sebastian: I don't think know of any way to "test" (i.e. SFINAE) a constructor call from a derived class. That is, unless I define all the abstract methods first, so that the derived class isn't abstract anymore. But that doesn't work for the generic case, where the class is a template and you have no idea what the signatures of its abstract methods are.